# How to write the inherit class as i cannot understand how to write the code properly

Tags: python

'''
Write 3 classes - Derived class, base_1 class, and base_2 class. The derived class should inherit base_1 and base_2 classes. Any derived class object created should be initiated with 2 variables - a,b. Any base_1 class object created should be initiated with variable a and base_2 class object should be initiated with variable b. On creating a base_1 class object, a new variable c should be attributed to the object with the value 5*a. On creating a base_2 class object, a new variable d should be attributed to the object with the value 10*b. Write a python program to create a derived class object with a=2,b=3 and print the 2 new variables (c,d) created.

Code:
class a():
def a(self):
self.a= 5
print("The vaile")

class b():
def b(self):
self.b= 6

class c(a):
def c(self):
C= 5*a.a(self)
print("C")

ob = c()
ob.print
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Base1:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.c = 5*self.a
class Base2:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        self.d = 10*self.b
class Derived(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        Base1.__init__(self, a)
        Base2.__init__(self, b)

    def print(self):
        print(self.c, self.d)
Derived(2, 3).print()
```

Output `10 30`